# Locating multiple zero values in large cell array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, loops, indexing

I'm having some trouble writing a MATLAB code that needs to locate the max value of each cell of my one cell array, `vel_data`, a `1x430` cell containing several excel sheets worth of data consisting of `M` rows x `1` column. I want to extract the max value, as well as every value before and after that max value until the first `0` is reached into a new cell array.

e.g. if the first cell in the array were `[3 2 1 0 2 6 4 3 0 1 0]` it would extract the values `[0 2 6 4 3 0]` and do so for every cell in the array.

I know the following extracts the max values of the cell array but I would like for it to do as I mentioned above.

```
d=dir(f);
for n=1:numel(d)
    max_vel{n} = deal(max(vel_data{n}));
end
```

Any advice/sample code would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First index of max value extracted as `idx`. Then indexes of all elements that are 0 extracted as `f1`. Index of the element that is 0 and is immediately before max value extracted as `f2`. and `f3` is index of the element that is 0 and is immediately after max value.

```
vel_data = {[3 1 0 2 6 4 0 1 0] , [1 1 0 9 3 0 4 6 9]}
for n=1:numel(vel_data)
    data = vel_data{n};
    [~,idx] = max(data);
    f1 = find(data==0);
    if isempty(f1)
        max_vel{n} = data;
        continue;
    end
    f2 = find(f1 < idx,1,'last');
    f3 = find(f1 > idx,1);
    if isempty(f2)
        idx_first = 1;
    else
        idx_first =f1(f2);
    end
    if isempty(f3)
        idx_last = numel(data);
    else
        idx_last =f1(f3);
    end 
    max_vel{n} = data(idx_first:idx_last);
end
```

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. To find the last zero and first zero after a max value is extracted you indexed the max value first then extracted all the zeroes in the cell containing 0 and then extracted the two values using f2, f3.

Comment: The problem is that I think this method, extracts the max value of the entire cell array whereas I need this to extract the max of every cell in the array. Additionally, my first attempt running this code  yielded: Error using horzcat; Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent from the max_vel{n} line.

Comment: Can you explain more about the data? It is very useful if you provide a simple reduced size example and expected output.

Comment: Of course, sorry about the confusion: in my original question note that the data is a large cell array 1x430 containing several excel spreadsheets of velocity outputs that are M rows x 1 column for each cell in the array. So the first cell in the array could be 50 x 1, the second 80x1, third 30x1... For shorthand say cells 1 and 2 are 7x1 and 9 x 1. 1 = [3 1 0 2 6 4 0 1 0] and 2 = [1 1 0 9 3 0 4 6 9] I would expect the output to be max_vel{n} = [0 2 6 4 0], [0 9 3 0] ...

Comment: sorry there were a problem ,you are right I updated the answer.

Comment: I see, this was the approach I attempted at first though I continuously ran into the error index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: this is because your data is not as you described

Comment: I understand that the vel_data I had written was shorthand for my cell array that contains 430 cells, though I'm not sure why it would limit the indexing to the first 10 cells. Thanks again!

Comment: I changed the program and added some conditions see if it works

Comment: Same issue. To avoid any further confusion the 1x430 cell array contains doubles of varying Mx1 size e.g. 1 = 407 x 1, 2 = 27861x1, 3 = 36950x1... I guess this is where my main source of confusion is - why would the index exceed matrix dimensions? The code written should create a new cell array 1x430 containing the max value and every value before and after that max value until a zero is found.

Comment: still have the index exceeds matrix error in the idx_last = f1(f2+1)

Comment: I want to know why this only works for a small data set as mentioned before vel_data contains much larger doubles such that just the first 5 cells are vel_data = [407x1], [27861x1], [36950x1], [22600x1], [21600x1], [678x1] and so on for 425 more cells. I need this loop to work for every double in the vel_data set but at the moment it only works for the first 14.

Comment: @rahnema1 You're doing too much work for very little gain. I would have stopped after the second edit.  This OP shouldn't have to deal out information piece meal. Everything should have been provided at the beginning.

Comment: @rayryeng you are right. it seems that OP should learn how to debug

Comment: @rahnema1 I agree. I've given you an upvote for your effort, even though the OP doesn't deserve your help.

Comment: It would have been just 10 if it weren't for me!